# SQLite syntax error during trigger creation

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Running the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ts_in AFTER INSERT ON events
BEGIN
   UPDATE events SET timestamp = datetime() WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

I get an error:

> Error: near "CREATE TRIGGER ts_in": syntax error

I can run the update statement independently just fine (I have to specify an id).

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine.... How are you executing the create statement?

Comment: Via the sqlite shell. I began getting a more meaningful error when I took the time to completely retype the command from scratch. I think I may have copied a bad whitespace character or something somewhere